# How can I forward a chart from my servlet to jp?

Tags: jsp, servlets, jfreechart, requestdispatcher

I've builded a servlet which make some Query to a database pick some information up and them forward it to the jsp page.

Apart of this information, now I wanted to include, as a request, a chart which has been created in the servlet.

Servlet code:

```
 public void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

 . More Servlet code..
 .
 .
 . 
 case "Charts": {

            String QueryStatus = "select distinct NodeStatus from nodes;";

            Operations oper = new Operations();


            ArrayList<?> ListStatus = oper.getList(QueryStatus);              



            request.setAttribute("ListStatus", ListStatus);
```

Till here everything works well, but once i add the following code:

```
            JFreeChart Chart = null;
            BACENGQueryDatabases DataChart = new BACENGQueryDatabases();
            Chart = DataChart.GetChart("select Name, StNode from controls;");

            if (Chart != null) {
                int width = 500;
                int height = 350;
                final ChartRenderingInfo info = new ChartRenderingInfo(new    StandardEntityCollection());
                response.setContentType("image/png");
                OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
                ChartUtilities.writeChartAsPNG(out, Chart, width, height, info);
            }
```

The chart is printed but nothing else. The RequestDispatcher is truncate.

```
          RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/Charts.jsp"); //Set page to redirect data
            rd.forward(request, response);// Forward data to the next page
            break;
        }
```

Is there any way to forward the chart, like I'm doing with ( request.setAttribute("ListStatus", ListStatus);) to be used on the same jsp page.

I refuse to use print the chart to a file and then use it on jsp because the I/O performance, since many charts will be created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A single response can only have one content type. It is either a normal HTML page (type = `text/html`) or a chart (type = `image/png`) but not both.

As you forward to a JSP, I presume you want to build an HTML page containing a chart (in fact a png image). You include the image in the HTML file with an `<img>` tag. At this point you have 2 possibilities :

- a simple and classical `<img>` where the source is an URL. The browser will issue a second request **at the url you give** and then you send directly the image. Simple and robust, but needs 2 requests.
- a base 64 embedded image. The `src`attribute **contains** the base64 encoded image, something like

  ```
  src="data:image/png;base64,__base64 encoded image__"
  ```

  You save one request, but if your image is large, the encoding will give a an increase in size between 30% and 40%. And it is not always correctly understood by all browsers. You should look at this other post [Embedding Base64 Images](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1207190) for more details.

Comment: Great!!! finally I've decided to indicate the Url and it works as I wanted. I was trying with [<jsp:include page="URL" />] but it got into a loop asking to login all the time, I don't know way.. Thanks.